# How to calculate some points given a range of numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

Math was a long time ago and I am not sure what I want, nor how to calculate it. Imagine I know I have the numbers from 1 to 100.  I want to give the user a picker/combination box to be able to select some of these numbers.  But I do not want all the numbers in the picker.  Maybe it shows the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,25,40,60,80,90,100.  In my words it goes up slowly in the beginning and then becomes steeper later.  I think that an exponential function is too steep.

Ultimately I would love it if someone could show me how to create an objective C method which accepts two numbers and returns and array of NSNumbers similar to what I have shown above.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Try linear func, e.g. `f(x)=2x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Sequence of Triangular Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) ?

**Equation :** x<sub>n</sub> = n(n+1)/2

**Sequence *(start at n = 0)*** : 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, 210, 231, 253, 276, 300, 325, 351, 378, 406, 435, 465, 496, 528, 561, ...

Input : 1 to 100

> Min value = 1  , Max value = 100
>
> 1 + **0** = 1
>
> 1 + **1** = 2
>
> 2 + **3** = 5
>
> 5 + **6** = 11
>
> 11 + **10** = 21
>
> 21 + **15** = 36
>
> 36 + **21** = 57
>
> *and so on.. until the evaluated number exceeds max value*
>
> **Sequence :** 1, 2, 5, 11, 21, 36, 57 and so on ...

Input : 1000 to 10000

> Min value = 1000 , Max value = 10000
>
> 1000 + **0** = 1000
>
> 1000 + **1** = 1001
>
> 1001 + **3** = 1004
>
> 1004 + **6** = 1010
>
> 1010 + **10** = 1020
>
> 1020 + **15** = 1035
>
> 1035 + **21** = 1056
>
> *and so on.. until the evaluated number exceeds max value*
>
> **Sequence :** 1000, 1001, 1004, 1010, 1020, 1035, 1056 and so on ...

I will leave the implementation part for you to try it out.

Comment: Hi guys. That's really great I had never heard of that series. But it's is still too steep for example this is the first few 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, and 75025. I would like something that does not go up so quick.

Comment: OH ! Okay. I think I found the right one for you. I will make an edit to my post in a few mins.

Comment: I hope this one will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

i have written some code to generate

```
-(NSArray *)generateNumbersFromBeginning:(int)begin toEnd:(int)end withCount:(int)count
{
    NSMutableArray * genNumbers=[NSMutableArray new];

    double sqBegin=1.0; //our beginning generator

    double sqEnd  =sqrt((double)(end-begin)); // last element to produce

    double step = (sqEnd-sqBegin)/((double)count);//

    double power=1.0;

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f",sqBegin,sqEnd,step);

    for (int a= 0; a<count; a++) {

        sqBegin+=step;

        power += 1.0/(double)count;

        int genNumber=(int)(pow(sqBegin, power));

        genNumber+=begin;

        [genNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:genNumber]];

    }

    NSLog(@"numbers are: %@ ",genNumbers);

    return genNumbers;


}
```

the usage is ([a,b], x) where a is start point b is end point and x is the number of int generated in that range.

e.g:

```
[self generateNumbersFromBeginning:9000 toEnd:10000 withCount:36];
```

the result of this call is:

```
numbers are: (
    9001,
    9002,
    9003,
    9005,
    9006,
    9008,
    9010,
    9012,
    9014,
    9017,
    9021,
    9025,
    9029,
    9034,
    9041,
    9048,
    9056,
    9065,
    9076,
    9089,
    9104,
    9121,
    9141,
    9165,
    9192,
    9223,
    9259,
    9301,
    9350,
    9407,
    9473,
    9549,
    9638,
    9741,
    9860,
    9999
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but you could use a simple equation such as:

> f(x) = floor(x<sup>c</sup>) where c > 1

You could set c to whatever number gives the desired steepness. Eg. For c = 1.5, you would have:

> 0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 18, 22, 27, 31, 36, 41, 46, 52, 58, 64, 70, 76, 82, 89, 96, 103, 110, 117, 125...

To adjust for a different starting value, s, just do f(x, s) = floor(x<sup>c</sup>) + s.

---

Another possible function would be one that consists of a series of lines slowly increasing in steepness. For example, here is a "parabola" made of line segments:

> f(x, s) = 0.5cd(floor(x/d))<sup>2</sup> + 0.5cd(floor(x/d)) + c(floor(x/d) + 1)(x mod d) + s

where c and d are constants (≥ 1) of your choosing (and the derivation is slightly irritating). c is the slope of the initial line, d represents how long the line segments are. s is again the starting value. For example, let  s = 100, c = 3, d = 4, and you have the following sequence (for x = 0, 1, 2, ...):

> 100, 103, 106, 109, 112, 118, 124, 130, 136, 145, 154, 163, 172, 184, 196, 208, 220, 232, 247...

Now if we wanted "round" numbers we would set c and s to a "round" number. But if we wanted to start counting by ones, we could define something like:

```
g(x) = x             when x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
     = f(x - 5, 5)   when x ≥ 5
```

So if c = 5, and d = 5, we have a sequence like:

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 95, 110, 125, 140, 155, 175, 195, 215, 235, 255, 280, 305, 330, 355, 380, 410, 440, 470, 500, ...

---

*And of course, to stop before the given max value, just stop evaluating the function when it returns a number greater than the desired max.